# When is a $\Sigma_n$ Skolem hull a proper submodel?

Tags: set-theory, model-theory, constructibility, fine-structure

For $M$ an amenable structure and $X \subset M$, the $\Sigma_n$ Skolem hull of $X$ is a $\Sigma_n$-elementary submodel of $M$. That is, as presentend in Devlin, *Constructibility*, pp. 85-88, for $h_n$ a $\Sigma_n$ Skolem function of $M$, if $h_n(\omega \times X)$ is closed under ordered pairs,
$$
h_n(\omega \times X) \prec_n M
$$

However, in practice, we may have $h_n(\omega \times X) = M$ ; in which case the conclusion becomes uninteresting. Hence my question.

> What can we suppose on $M$ and $X$ in order to ensure that we obtain a *proper* elementary submodel ? What happens in the case where $M = L_\alpha$ for some ordinal $\alpha$ ?

I know that having another elementary submodel $N \prec_n M$ with $X \subset N$ is sufficient but then it somehow loses its purpose of creating a new submodel.

Edit : As this looks too broad, here are more details on my issue. Let $\alpha < \beta < \gamma$ be countable limit ordinals such that $L_\alpha \prec_n L_\beta$. Writing $H^\gamma_n(X)$ the $\Sigma_n$ Skolem hull of $X$ in $L_\gamma$,

> What can we say about $H^\gamma_n(L_\alpha)$ and $H^\gamma_n(L_\beta)$ ? Under what conditions are they  proper submodels of $L_\gamma$ ? And different from one another ?

Comment: Can you ask a more precise question? Some examples: (assuming ZFC) if the cardinality of $\omega+X$ is $<$ that of $M$. Or if $M\models\mathrm{ZF}^-$ and $X$ is bounded in $M$ and $n<\omega$. One can also have examples when $M=L_\alpha$, even with the transitive collapse of $h_n(\omega\times X)$ being $L_\alpha$ itself (at least assuming $0^\#$ on the outside, though this might be overkill).

Comment: Yes, thank you for those leads. I've added more details on the issue I'm facing.

Comment: I believe that $H_n^\gamma(L_\alpha)=L_\alpha$, since for any $\Sigma_n$-Skolem function $f_\phi$ and any $c\in L_\alpha$, we have $L_\gamma\vDash f(c)\textrm{ is defined}$, and this reflects to $L_\alpha\vDash f(c)\textrm{ is defined}$, i.e. $L_\alpha$ closed under $f$. Maybe usage of $H_n^\gamma(L_\alpha\cup\{L_\alpha\})$ may be more common for constructing superstructures of $L_\alpha$